# Add required bundle to existing MANIFEST.MF

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, manifest

I need to add one or more dependencies to the Require-Bundle header of an existing eclipse plugin MANIFEST.MF. How can i do this using maven/tycho?

Comment: I don't get your question. The bundle dependencies have to be specified in the `MANIFEST.MF` and Tycho will get and resolve those dependencies based on your target definition. Unlike a regular Maven project where the dependencies are specified in the `pom.xml` which is only required at compile time, in an OSGi bundle the dependencies have to be declared in the `MANIFEST.MF` since they are also required at runtime (OSGi bundles can be installed, started, stopped and uninstalled at runtime).

Comment: Yep, the bundle dependencies are specified in the MANIFEST.MF, and right before the compiled bundle is packaged, i need to add one more (runtime) dependency to the list of dependencies already present in the Require-Bundle header.

Comment: You can use e.g. the `maven-resources-plugin` or `maven-antrun-plugin` Maven plugin to add or modify files between compiling and packing (`<phase>prepare-package</phase>`) or before compiling (`<phase>process-resources</phase>`).